# Why does libxml2_xpath fails by Invalid FFI pointer type, expected null, or External

Tags: docker, macos, deno

Using Denos libxml2_xpath in a Pipline Application fails even under docker

running

```
docker run  
\--interactive  \\ 
\--tty   \\ 
\--platform linux/amd64   
\--rm     
\--volume $PWD:/app    
\--volume $HOME/.deno:/deno-dir    
\--workdir /app     
deno deno run --allow-read --allow-ffi --unstable examples/parse-xcb.ts
```

fails by

```
error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Invalid FFI pointer type, expected null, or External
this.#ptr = lib.symbols.xmlCreatePushParserCtxt(
^
at new PushParseCtxt (https://deno.land/x/libxml2_xpath@v0.0.3/mod.ts:89:29)
at parseDocument (https://deno.land/x/libxml2_xpath@v0.0.3/mod.ts:442:17)
at eventLoopTick (ext:core/01_core.js:183:11)
at async file:///app/examples/parse-xcb.ts:9:15
```

Dockefile on Macbook M1

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 denoland/deno:1.37.0

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive  \
apt-get update                      \
&& apt-get install -qy              \
libxml2-utils                       \
libxml2-dev                         \
libxml2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**That third-party lib is outdated** (https://deno.land/x/libxml2_xpath), it's using `pointer` type when it should be `buffer` since it's passing a `Uint8Array`

https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/runtime/ffi_api#supported-types

> As of Deno 1.25, **the pointer type has been split into a pointer and a**
> **buffer type** to ensure users take advantage of optimizations for Typed
> Arrays, and as of Deno 1.31 the JavaScript representation of pointer
> has become an opaque pointer object or null for null pointers.

Once you change the source from that lib from:

```
  "xmlCreatePushParserCtxt": {
    parameters: ["pointer", "pointer", "pointer", "usize", "pointer"],
    result: "pointer",
    nonblocking: false,
  },
```

to:

```
 "xmlCreatePushParserCtxt": {
    parameters: ["pointer", "pointer", "buffer", "usize", "buffer"],
    result: "pointer",
    nonblocking: false,
  },
```

You no longer encounter that error. However, other errors get triggered because the library is quite outdated. It uses the unstable FFI API, which requires that the project be kept up to date.

---

If you then change the constructor to:

```
  constructor(chunk: Uint8Array) {
    this.#ptr = lib.symbols.xmlCreatePushParserCtxt(
      null,
      null,
      chunk,
      chunk.length,
      cstr("<mem>"),
    );
    if (typeof this.#ptr !== 'object') {
      throw new Error(`${this.#ptr}`);
    }
  }
```

The lib no longer crashes when calling `parseDocument(stream)`. But it crashes when using `XPathContext(doc)`. It won't work until you replace all the outdated FFI types.

You should find a new library or update that one completely.